# 404 Error When the file exists, New Files seem Blocked

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am editing a website for a client and have hit a bit of a roadblock. Most of the website is done in php if that matters. I can edit and publish existing pages just fine, but if I were to create a new .php or .html page and try to view it online, I get sent to the 404 error page. Initially I thought this had to do with the .htaccess files but I could not find anything wrong there. If I take the same exact code from the page I want to add and overwrite an existing page with the code, it works fine. Below is the code for the .htaccess file that only includes a rewrite. I can't think of what may be blocking me from viewing my new pages. I appreciate the help guys!

Edit: It appears the htaccess  file below is the issue, when deleted everything works fine but I loose my rewrites. Can anyone suggest a better way to accomplish the rewrites in htaccess to allow surfing without extension names? Eg. website.com/home instead of website.com/home.php

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|uploads|db|fonts|blogger|support|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Check to see if you have a whitelist for accepted pages somewhere in one of the PHP-files, is my best guess.

Comment: If you comment out those lines in your `.htaccess` file, does the behavior change?

Comment: @Zak 
If I delete the .htaccess file, everything works fine. Can you suggest a different way to have my rewrite rules so that both work? In other words, the htaccess file is meant to allow website.com/home instead of website.com/home.php 

How can I still do that without deleting htaccess. Thanks Zak.

Comment: The easiest way to remove extensions is to use directories instead of files... ie `example.com/home/` instead of `example.com/home/index.php`. But that wouldn't be very practical in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the extensions in your .htaccess file .. This is what I use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.htm [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hey, still having some problems when using your .htaccess rules. It looks like the file is making the server look in root for the webpage (The requested URL /signup.php was not found on this server.), when it is actually in application/views/signup.php.  It seems the rules in my OP are important but at the same time make it impossible to add a new page without 404 errors. Can you suggest a way to tweak my rules to work with any new pages? Or at least make your rules redirect to /application/views/ ? Much appreciated.